# Size of bubbles in a influence plot

Tags: regression, python, least-squares, statsmodels

I'm running an OLS regression and using the Python package [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/index.html) to explore the role of residuals.

Specifically, I am creating an influence plot as illustrated in [this](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/example_regression_plots.html#Influence-plots) tutorial.

I wonder why the plot results in a bubble one with variable bubble sizes and what information does the bubble size.

This here is the image extracted from the tutorial linked above, which has been created on a dataset via

```
prestige = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Duncan", "car", cache=True).data
prestige_model = ols("prestige ~ income + education", data=prestige).fit()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
fig = sm.graphics.influence_plot(prestige_model, ax=ax, criterion="cooks")
```

[image]

What is the size of the bubble telling me? There doesn't seem to be an explanation in the [docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.influence_plot.html?highlight=influence_plot).

Comment: The documention says: "criterion : str {‘DFFITS’, ‘Cooks’} Which criterion to base the size of the points on. Options are DFFITS or Cook’s D."

Comment: Note: there was a bug in statsmodels 0.6.1 where the criteria where switched https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3103 It is fixed in 0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation of influence_plot](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.influence_plot.html) is not verbose, but it seems clear that point size is [Cook's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook's_distance). Other statistical packages (in R, for example) make similar plots using contour lines for Cook's distance instead of point size.